# Dropdown nav menus break when I call the nav from within a directory using the following code:

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Building fresh from Bootstrap 3.3.4. Nav dropdown works fine on pages in the root directory, but when I call the nav in the header in a directory using:

```
    <?php
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php');
    ?>
```

It pulls everything but the dropdown navs don't work.

Any ideas what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calling only the header part of your page. The bootstrap and jquery breaks if their code is inserted in the page more than once. Hence,
make sure that you are calling the bootstrap libraries and relevant jquery libraries in right order and only once in any page.

Something like this :-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <!--You code -->
</body>
 <!-- javascript files-->
</html>
```